# R 'secr' package

Tags: r

I'm trying to use **secr.fit()** in **secr** package.

```
> C<- read.capthist('captfile4.txt', 'trapfile2.txt',detector = 'proximity')
 No errors found :-)  
> secr0 <- secr.fit(C, model = g0~1, buffer = 100, trace = FALSE)" 
 "Error in uniroot(naiveRPSVcall, lower = obsRPSV/10, upper = obsRPSV *  :    f() values at end points not of opposite sign 
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf 
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf 
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 
Error in naivecap2(0.001, sigma = tempsigma, cap = cpa) :    NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)" .
```

Can anyone please tell me why I get this error? Thank You.

Comment: Can you post a code example that reproduces the error? Hard to speculate without it.

Comment: What was the design like? Photo-trap, a hair snare? I'm asking because you left out the detection function and I'm curious as to why.